# Set Reference Application from Controller?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

New to JAVAFX so this maybe a simple fix, but I have controllers in my application setup using FXML files. I reference the controller to use via the FXML file and to load the file i use the following code in my Application class

```
private void replaceScene(String resource) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));

        Pane screen = (Pane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(screen);
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/css/application.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();

        IControlledScreen controller = (IControlledScreen) loader.getController();
        controller.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot load resource " + resource);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is a basic controller

```
public class MyController implements IControlledScreen {

    MyApplication app;

    public void setApp(MyApplication application) {
        app = application;
    }


    @FXML
    public Button btnStart;

    // Initialises the controller class.
    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        btnStart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // code here
            }

        });
    }

}
```

I have also got an interface called IControlledScreen to set the reference to the application

```
public interface IControlledScreen { 

    // ALlows us a reference to the application
    public void setApp(MyApplication app); 

}
```

Now this all works fine, until i try to access the app variable during the initialize event.  So changing the above controller to this now breaks, because app = NULL.

```
public class MyController implements IControlledScreen {

    MyApplication app;

    public void setApp(MyApplication application) {
        app = application;
    }


    @FXML
    public Button btnStart;

    // Initialises the controller class.
    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        // HERE app = NULL
        app.GetSomeProperty = "";
    }

}
```

How can i get round this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you have to change your design. 
The initialize method is called during FXMLLoader.load()
So the call stack would be something like

```
..replaceScene
..loader.load
....MyController.initialize()
..loader.getController
..controller.setApp(app)
```

If you really have to access the application from inside your controller you would need to make it a singleton.

Comment: I agree this is a bad design: components represented by an FXML-Controller pair should not be coupled to the application class that uses them. If you do want to do this, though, you can also usually avoid referencing the `app` reference in the `initialize()` method, and just initialize anything that relies on it in the `setApp(...)` method. This would avoid having to make your application class a singleton.